# VS express 2010 - csv formatted data

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am new to programming, I need to create a small program where i have one field with a couple of hundred numeric records and need to add a csv type format to these records.

i.e.:

original data:
123122
232432
32323434
2423434
54545

required:

'123122',
'232432',
'32323434',
'2423434',
'54545',

Then I can copy into my queries . I am able to do this for one record but not for more. Also, I can do this in excel but need to have it set in a program.

Comment: sample code of what you have done so far is very useful when asking for help.  Also, what programming language are you using.  Third, where is the data coming from, IE text file, Excel file, DB Query.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just add single quotes at the beginning and end, and replace the space with "','".

Another approach is to use arrayList